# Import PHP page onto HTML document

Tags: php, html, css, import

I have created a navbar.php for my navigation elements. How would I go about importing that navbar to my index.html in order to make a functioning navbar across all my html pages? Do I have to convert my html pages to php? Do you I have to remake each page individually for a navbar?

Thank you for your help

here is a screenshot of my folder directory:
[directory listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLaKs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PHP include is all it takes.  An include will insert the HTML (or PHP) wherever you put your include.

PHP is a server side language.  Meaning that the file is assembled by the server and then sent over to the client.  So, PHP include is basically reading the file and inserting it directly into the document.

**somePage.php**

```
<?php include "navbar.php" ?>
THIS IS GREAT CONTENT
```

**navbar.php**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Great link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">I don't like this link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This link is cool</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Links are the bomb</a></li>
</ul>
```

Per the poster's comment:

Here's how to do it in JavaScript:

**navbar.html**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Great link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">I don't like this link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This link is cool</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Links are the bomb</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, let's rewrite our somePage.  Note that the file extensions are now .html, meaning everything is parsed **client side**.  So, after the page has loaded, our code is telling the browser to go out and fetch navbar.html and then insert it into our div with the id "navBar".

**somePage.html**

```
<div id="navBar"></div>
THIS IS GREAT CONTENT

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.get("navbar.html", function (data) {
    $("#navBar").html(data);
});
</script>
```

This is definitely a hack, please don't use this:

**somePage.html**

```
<div id="navBar">

</div>
THIS IS GREAT CONTENT

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="navbar.html"></script>
```

**navbar.html**

```
$("#navBar").html(`<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Great link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">I don't like this link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This link is cool</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Links are the bomb</a></li>
</ul>`);
```

Comment: did that nothing happened

Comment: do you have webserver running?

Comment: I would recommend WAMP or XAMPP as webservers.

Comment: oh no i forgot to mention that this is strictly practice and hosted locally lemme guess i need a wesberver

Comment: You do need a webserver to run any PHP code, but, if you want, I can easily rewrite it in JavaScript.

Comment: Could you possibly explain both (php locally, and javascript method)

Comment: They both have been inserted (with explanations).  If you could mark as answer, that would really help.

Comment: I will be sure to mark it answer once i get it working i am truly a novice that is why i am practicing still can not get it working im trying java currently

Comment: JavaScript and Java are very different languages, just a heads up.  I wrote mine in JavaScript.

Comment: could you tell me what i am doing wrong [link](https://i.gyazo.com/3a7959db7d500904ad74fcc5cdba410e.png)

Comment: I just remembered something, I'm sorry for not giving you the heads up.  But if you're serving local system files... you can't use external sources because of cross origin and basic browser security.  Well, there is one last hack that you can do... but it just that, a hack.  Just use a PHP server and save yourself a lot of hassle.  Anyway I'll post the hack.

Comment: okay because im trying to get all the kinks worked out before i try publishing

Comment: Updated.  I would highly recommend not using that.  But, ultimately, it will work even if in a nuclear shelter.  So, have fun, lol.

Comment: I want to give you at least some direction, so you could use apache portable ( https://apr.apache.org/ ), if you want it to be installable on anyone's computer.  Or, if you're planning to make it into a website, simply use xampp and then upload it and the functionality will be way easier to manage.

Comment: well again I am a novice so that probably wont happen for a  bit I've learned all my coding from books issued in 2003. and overall the wesbite i just started like three days ago its fairly simple

Comment: Hmmm.. you might have better luck with an online IDE (which can process php perfectly).  How about https://c9.io/, they do charge monthly (just a heads up), but it is well worth the money.  https://codeanywhere.com/ is completely free but a little bit harder to setup.

Comment: do you have a discord because i might ask questions later also, I use Vscode and sublime text 3 sometimes atom i am probably gonna remove atom due to the slowness even though I have two packages.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all pages in php (index.php), same directory in this case.

Use

```
include_once "navbar.php";
```

to import your navbar into page.

Example of index.php

```
<?php
include_once "navbar.php";
?>
Your html code
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and simple help :D